# Proving that an exponential divergent sequence divided by the same divergent sequence diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to solve this problem in my real analysis book.
Here it is:
Let $b>1, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, a_n \rightarrow +\infty$. Prove:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b^{a_n}}{({a_n})^{\alpha}} = +\infty$$
To solve this problem I must first do this:
$$ 
\frac{b^{ \lfloor a_n \rfloor}}{(\lfloor a_n \rfloor+1)^{\alpha}} \leq \frac{b^{a_n}}{(a_n)^{\alpha}}
$$
and than use
$$ 
\frac{b^{n}}{({n})^{\alpha}} \rightarrow +\infty
$$
Ultimately I must use the squeeze theorem. I can only use sequences and their theorems.
I understand why the second sequence (the one with the floor functions) is always smaller than the first one. I understand why the third sequence is divergent. I just don't see how they come together to prove the original claim.

Comment: I can't find a way to implement the floor function in Mathjax.

Comment: `$\lfloor a_n \rfloor$` gives $\lfloor a_n \rfloor$, you can find that e.g. here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/42969

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it.